# What am I getting wrong about Java's '==' and '.equals'?

Tags: java, object

EDIT: I'm new to java and am going through the official documentation in preparation for an upcoming subject in my Computer Science studies.

Original question:

So I checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java) re: java `==` and `.equals` and am getting some unexpected results in dummy code that I'm writing.

I have this:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Double double1 = 1.0;  //object 1
        Double double2 = 1.0;  //object 2, which should be a different memory address?

        System.out.println(double1.equals(double2)); //compare using the Object.equals() method 
        System.out.println(double1 == double2); //compare with ==
    }
}
//Results are:
//true
//false
```

As expected, `==` produces a `false` because the two objects refer to different memory addresses.

However the `double.equals(double2)` is producing a `true`, which is not what I expected. In this example, I'm not overriding the default `.equals()` inherited from `Object`. My understanding is that `equals` checks for reference equality as well as values.

So why does `double1.equals(double2)` return `true` instead of `false` in this example? Are't `double1` and `double2` referring to two difference objects and therefore `equals()` should return `false`?

Comment: As an aside, be aware that floating point number normally cannot be compared for exact equality.  Instead you check if they differ by a small amount.  Two floating point numbers are almost never "equal", you want to check if they differ by for example .000000001 and call them "equal" if their difference is less than that.  The exact value would depend on the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't override `equals`, but the implementation of `java.lang.Double` does override it, to return true if the underlying values compare equal (plus a couple of edge cases).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that equals checks for reference equality as well as values.

That is incorrect.

The version of `equals(Object)` defined by `java.lang.Object` does that.  But many classes *override* `equals(Object)` to have different semantics.

`Double` overrides it, and so do all of the other "primitive wrapper" classes, and `String` ... and many, many more.

The semantics of the override are *typically* equal-by-value, but not always.  And some classes don't override `equals`.  Examples where `equals` is not overridden that trip people up are `StringBuilder` and array types!

To find out the semantics for `SomeType.equals(Object)` you need to start with the javadocs for `SomeType` ... not `Object`.